# java.lang.NullPointerException at android.widget.PopupWindow$PopupViewContainer.dispatchKeyEvent(PopupWindow.java:1445)

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-actionbar

I have crash, when I am using app.

I don't use PopupWindow.

Any idea where is problem?

I am using ActionBar.

Error from Android 2.3.3

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.widget.PopupWindow$PopupViewContainer.dispatchKeyEvent(PopupWindow.java:1445)
at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverKeyEventToViewHierarchy(ViewRoot.java:2694)
at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverKeyEvent(ViewRoot.java:2659)
at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1953)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4196)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I guess from here is the problem.

```
  @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_article, menu);

        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);
        mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider)MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(item);       
        setShareIntent();

        return true;
    }

    private void setShareIntent() {

        try {

            RssItem rssitem = (RssItem) fragments.get(pager.getCurrentItem()).getArguments().get("item");

            Intent shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(ActivityArticlesScroll.this)
            .setType("text/plain").setText(rssitem.getTitle()+"\n\n"+rssitem.getLink()).getIntent();

            if (mShareActionProvider != null) {
                mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show related codes ?

Comment: I think problem is with ShareActionprovider, but I am not sure.

Comment: there must be something null in PopupWindow.java file at Line no 1445. please check it once

Comment: Your issue coming from `ShareActionProvider` becoz `ShareActionProvider` itself a `PopUpWindow` so you must close this `ShareActionProvider` before you navigate to another `View` or `Page`.